# Can I pre-compile a single modified page to an already preCompiled .Net Web Site?

Tags: asp.net, precompiled

I have many usercontrols that i reuse in different projects. They are all in the web site project. Upon making extension for a new customer, I am precompiling the complete web site and deploy it (with around 600 items *UserControls & Pages* in it). If I have to make a small modification on any page and want to deploy it I have to pre-compile whole project which takes around 15-20 minutes on my machine.

Is there a way to precompile and deploy only modified or selected items of a web site?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After long searches the answer is NO!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you put your `UserControls` into their own projects([Web Deployment Projects](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=24509)) within the same solution, however many needed, which will compile them into .dlls:

**ie:**

```
Namespace.Module1.UI.dll

Namespace.Module2.UI.dll    

Namespace.Module3.UI.dll
```

Comment: Problem is that many people are working on it. And it has never been splitted before. And unfortuantely they are to much bound to each other which makes it extremely difficult to remove from each other. I am the developer who is coding on top of it this customization. I would do also many UI DLLs if I have done it all by myself or with my crew. But we have to work on what we have :-(

Comment: Doesn't matter, the main project can reference other projects and build just like it does all together.

Comment: Thank you! I will read the article throughly and let's see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you publish using "allow this precompiled site to be updatable", you can precompile certain  things and only publish those.
For example, if you only changed code in .cs files since the last publish, you can sometimes get away with only publishing the new App_Code.dll, but there are some tricky situations… For example, if you changed code in .cs files that the code in one of your pages depends on, you might need to publish a new precompiled version of that page as well. (I asked about why this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9127165/why-do-i-need-a-recompiled-page-when-a-method-used-by-it-changes), but no one has given a good answer so far.)
You can even publish precompiled pages and user controls in some cases, but nasty situations may arise here as well. For example, if your page uses a Master Page and User Controls, you might need new precompiled versions of those as well.